# How to create a new instance in MSSQL Server using PowerShell, PS+WMI or C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell, wmi

To create extra named instances for a already installed MS-SQL server
 
I usually re-run the installer...
and choose to add a new instance supplying the new name...

How can I do this from Powershell???
(I installed the SQLServer module but there is no 'New-Instance' commandlet there...)

Googlin' I saw some solution with Powershell+WMI but couldn't find one for new instance creation...

In last case...
if this can be done with c# (cs/csx) it is also an option...

?any ideas,,, Thx!

Comment: Excellent Question.   Why would anyone downvote this question?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to add a additional named instance is to use the installer.  You can, [Install SQL Server from the Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-2017)  You can alternatively, run [SQL Server instances in Docker containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017&pivots=cs1-bash).

Comment: David, any chance in the future, creating another instance will be available from powershell?